# How do I set up Sonarr's download client?

Tags: bittorrent, qbittorrent

I'm currently using qBittorent. Would setting up the Web User Interface somehow make it insecure? Is there a way to have qBittorent listen to Sonarr on my computer ONLY?

I'm sorry if this is pretty sparse, I'm having trouble finding the words for my question. Will edit this more to become readable.

Comment: either limit it to 127.0.0.1 or limit it via firewall, if your using a vps for that activity, a reverse proxy can be used with authentication while the interface was bound to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Can I type in localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 to achieve the same effect?

Comment: technically yes, but 127.0.0.1 would kill the lookup which might be a milli second faster in case of many request imho

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Comment: did it work what I suggest?

Comment: It does. Thank you!

Comment: I add the same as answer please accept my request it would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either limit it to 127.0.0.1 or limit it via firewall,

if your using a vps for that activity, a reverse proxy can be used with authentication while the other web or app instance may use the interface wto be bound to 127.0.0.1